# A simple image upload

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm pretty new to Symfony and stumbled upon an issue with adding a simple image upload to one of my forms.

```
 ## DefaultController.php ##
 /**
 *   @Route("/admini/articleadd", name="articleadd")
 */
 public function articleAdd(Request $request){
 $article = new Article();
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
    ->add('title', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('maxlenght' => 14)))
    ->add('text', TextareaType::class)
    ->add('image', FileType::class)
    ->add('add', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Article'))
    ->getForm();
 $form->handleRequest($request);
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $article = $form->getData();
        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
 $file = $article->getImage();
 $fileName = md5(uniqid());
 $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
 $article->setImage($fileName);
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $em->persist($article);
 $em->flush();
 return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
}
return $this->render('default/articleadd.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}

 #Article.php

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Article")
 */
 class Article
 {   //...// 
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" })
     */
    private $image;
    //...//
 }
```

So whenever I try to submit the form I get the message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function move() on null

So apparently "$file = $article->getImage()" returns as null?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) and if you want to learn more about file uploads in symfony you can read about it [here.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)

As for your problem it seems that the image field from form is null / empty which could suggest that you forgot to add to the form which vich sets it but i'm not sure about default FileType:class.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```